# Celery - How does countdown work?

Tags: python, celery

I want to understand how supplying a countdown=xx affect the scheduling of the task. According to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html?highlight=countdown#eta-and-countdown, setting countdown means that the task will take atleast xx seconds to execute.

What I want to know is how it is implemented. When we supply a task with a countdown value, is the task added to the queue but no workers pick it up or the workers pick up the task but defer it's execution until atleast the countdown value expires?

Answer (score 10):

The task is picked by a worker, but not acknowledged.

It means that if the power runs out, the task will be re-fetched by a different worker later.

The task's args/kwargs are kept in worker's memory until it's finished, so keep this in mind because you might run out of it really quick with lots of countdown tasks and large args/kwargs.

Comment: Does this mean that if one worker has picked up a task, other workers will not pick it up (even if not acknowledged)?

Also, what happens if a worker has picked up multiple tasks (in case a worker picks up tasks and buffers them) and all of their countdown values are the same)? What order will the tasks get executed?

Comment: The task should not be executed twice. I'm not sure about the order as well. However I won't relay on that. Write your core to be paralel and ensure following executions are safe.

Comment: Here is [a more in-depth answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/celery-users/uFwPg4b_1M4/78IUGq7tX8gJ) from the creator of celery.

Comment: Is it using CPU when waiting for the countdown to complete ?

Comment: I don't really know. I'd expect it to check the local queue for countdowns when picking new task / periodically when there are no processed tasks. But you can read the source code in order to find out this information.